# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key for library project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've a Xamarin.iOS app project which refers a Xamarin.iOS library project (class library).

I'm creating storyboard and ViewControllers in the library project, but for all outlets, I'm getting error

```
 this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 'outlet-name'
```

when I try to push/present a controller from the library project.

```
var vc = UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryBoardNameFromLibraryProject", null).InstantiateViewController("vcIdentifier");
PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
```

I getting the same error in a new solution too. I'm posting this question after many trials. I tried many things like product > clean, delete cache, delete bin, obj. But nothing seems to work.

### Edit

Here's the test project showing the error.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xf3JqRTFUczt06-h8j6NvMKvzh3ehknd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `using TestLib;` and cast the view controller to TestVC. This should work as expected :

```
private async void Func()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    var vc = UIStoryboard.FromName("TestSB", null).InstantiateViewController("testVC") as TestVC;
    PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
}
```

Comment: I used to cast only when I needed to set public properties in ViewControllers before present/push. Guess it wont work without casting when referring from class library.